# How do I make a dynamic index to get the value of a tuple?

Tags: rust, tuples

In Python, I learned that I can retrieve a tuple value by a dynamic index:

```py
data = (1,2,3,4)
data[0]

for a in range(len(data)):
   print(data[a])
```

The output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

how to do this in Rust?

I tried something like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = (12, 3, 4, 5);
    for a in 0..100 {
        println!("{}", data.a);
    }
}
```

But it's not working, it only gives me some error.

Comment: Please read [the book chapter 3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#the-tuple-type) for a detailed guide about tuples and other data types. You probably want an array or vec, not a tuple.

Comment: @hellow thank's for references,

Comment: I know that this is simple example, but please, next time, don't use _it only gives me some error_. You should copy & paste the error message as well.

Comment: because python value are dynamic this is "easily" but in Rust you have to use a collection then use dyn trait or enum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others pointed out, **you probably want to use an array or `Vec<T>` instead.**

As [the book explains](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#the-tuple-type), tuples are heterogeneous data types: each tuple element can have a different type. If you could iterate over all tuple values, strange things could happen:

```rust
let data = (12, true);
for a in 0..data.len() {
    // Oops: `+ 1` makes sense for the integer, but not for the bool
    println!("{}", data.a + 1); 
}
```

On the other hand, arrays are homogeneous types: all elements have the same type! So the problem in the snippet above can't occur. The same is true for `Vec<T>`: only elements of type `T` can be stored. The difference between `Vec<T>` and an array: a vector can grow, i.e. is dynamically sized while an array has a fixed size at compile time.

Here is your code snippet with an array ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9924db84caafcabf6eb489019fe4d273)):

```rust
let data = [12, 3, 4, 5];
for a in 0..data.len() {
    println!("{}", data[a]);
}
```

But of course, you can iterate over collections like arrays without iterating over indices, if you want (e.g. `for elem in &data`).

As a last note: of course, it's technically possible to create a dynamic tuple index by doing `unsafe` pointer magic – assuming you only store the same types in your tuple. But this is hardly ever necessary and should be avoided. That's why I won't even show code how to do it.

Comment: I would note that it would be possible to implement the `Index` and `IndexMut` traits on homogeneous tuples. The only question is "why would you use an homogeneous tuple, when you could use an array instead?"

Comment: thank's :) you make me understand now, your answer great, thanks 

Comment: Thanks :D finally got it