# why does not Rust tuple use square bracket to access elements inside?

Tags: rust

As titled.

In Rust, I need to use period syntax to access the elements inside a tuple like below (the `x.0`):

```
fn main() { 
    let x: (i32, f64, u8) = (500, 6.4, 1);
    println!("{}", x.0);
}
```

My question is why Rust does not support using a square bracket syntax to access the elements inside a tuple like below which should be a more consistent way?

```
fn main() { 
    // !!! this snippet of code would not be compiled !!!
    let x: (i32, f64, u8) = (500, 6.4, 1);
    println!("{}", x[0]);  // pay attention to the use of "x[0]" here.
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a dynamic index to get the value of a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520818/how-do-i-make-a-dynamic-index-to-get-the-value-of-a-tuple)

Comment: Somewhat of a duplicate? `[]` implies that every index would return the same type and (potentially) that the tuple would be iterable. That doesn't make sense for a tuple.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I don't think so, why in Python we can use such square syntax to access the value inside a tuple but not in Rust?

Comment: Rust isn't Python. These kind of "why" questions are usually unproductive because they invite speculation and rarely have a clear answer. Why does it matter? If the actual genuine reason is because a language inventor is a member of the Dot Mafia whose signature is leaving unnecessary periods in unusual places -- how is that in any way going to help you write code better?

Comment: Python can do that because it is dynamically typed. Rust isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The square bracket indexing syntax in Rust can always be used with a dynamic index. That means that the following code should work:

```rust
for i in 0..3 {
    do_something_with(x[i]);
}
```

Even if the compiler may not know which value `i` will take, it must know the type of `x[i]`. For heterogeneous tuple types like `(i32, f64, u8)` that's impossible. There is no type that is `i32`, `f64` and `u8` at the same time, so the traits [Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [IndexMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) can't be implemented:

```rust
// !!! This will not compile !!!

// If the Rust standard library allowed square-bracket indexing on tuples
// the implementation would look somewhat like this:
impl Index<usize> for (i32, f64, u8) {
    type Output = ???; // <-- What type should be returned?

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        match index {
            0 => &self.0,
            1 => &self.1,
            2 => &self.2,
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: (i32, f64, u8) = (500, 6.4, 1);
    for i in 0..3 {
        do_something_with(x[i]);
    }
}
```

Theoretically the standard library could provide an implementation for homogeneous tuples `(i32, i32, i32)` etc. but this is a corner case that can easily be replaced by an array `[i32; 3]`. So there is **no** such implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean curly bracket? Or square bracket?

Anyways, if my understanding of your question is a bit accurate,

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = [0; 5]; // which creates an array with 5 elements valued 0
    println!(“{}”, x[0]); // prints 0
}
```

pertains to accessing index 0 in an array named `x` and printing it.
Whilst `x.0` means index 0 of a tuple named `x`.

I’m not sure if we’re on the same page.

Perhaps this might shed a light on you for your question "why," https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html, look for **Table B-8: Tuples**. You'll see the *Non-Operator Symbol* used to access tuple elements (`expr.0`, `expr.1`).

And on **Table B-10: Square Brackets**, you'll see `expr[expr]`, as a way to access elements in a collection.

In my understanding they made it "that way", the "why" they made it that way, I'm not sure where to find them.

Comment: Sorry, just updated it, I mean the "square bracket". Why does Rust not support accessing elements inside a tuple with a square bracket syntax like "x[0]"?

Comment: Sorry I haven't got back to you in a long time. Perhaps I still fail to grasp why you're asking the question you're asking, consequentially impeding my ability to answer it.

I edited my attempted answer. My reply here is too long for my response.